# Current location plugin

Tags: plugins, geo-data

What plugin would you suggest that will show my current location (in GoogleMaps) at one single post (a post that gets updated each time I change a location).

I don't need a location for each of my blog posts, only a location for that one post. Updating my current location should be as easy as possible, preferably I would just have to input city name but would also have the ability to write coordinates if GoogleMaps doesn't recognize a city name.

Answer (score 1):

See which of the following works best for you:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-google-maps/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geo-location-comments/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-latitude-history/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plugin, that doesn't tie into Google Maps, but should be easier to update: http://wordpress.org/plugins/oh-hey-world/ (we built this since I had this same issue for 2+ years while traveling)